# Calculating the probability to die in a card game using Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-process, games

I saw this interesting question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskStatistics/comments/4tho1q/how_do_i_go_about_solving_this_question_regarding/) and couldn't figure it out.

### Situation

There is a special card in the game seen below:

[image: card]

Once this card gets played, there are 6 options that can happen. Only two options are relevant to the question:

1. You lose 3 health.
2. Repeat this process two more times (i.e. pick two options from the card at random again)

All of the options have the same probability of $1/6$ of happening once the card is played (e.g. with a dice throw).

### Question

**What is the probability of losing the game if you start with 20 health and draw the special card mentioned above?** You lose if your health is zero or less.

All other cards in the game are irrelevant because I'm only interested in the probability of dying with the special card.

**Example**

The only possible way to lower your health continuoulsy is to get the second option (i.e. chose another option two times) and then get the first option (-3 health). A possible chain to death could look something like this (numbers indicate options from above):

$2, 1~\text{(-3 health)}, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1$

After hitting option $1$ seven times, your health falls below 0 and it's game over.

### My attempt

I tried to tackle the problem using a Markov chain. As far as I see it, there are 5 states:

1. Irrelevant option, move ends
2. Health - 3, another move
3. Another 2 moves (i.e. option 2 from above)
4. Irrelevant option, another move
5. Health - 3, move ends

The transition matrix with state space $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ is as follows:

$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
4/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6  \\ 
0 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 4/6 & 0  \\ 
4/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

The canonical form of $M$ is:

$$
Q=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
1/6 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 4/6  \\ 
4/6 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Another difficulty is the first throw: Only options $1, 3$ or $5$ are possible at the start.

I tried to simulate it using random first options, but the probability of your health falling to 0 or below is so small that I never saw it once in hundreds of thousand of simulations.

Is there an analytic answer?

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question.  What are the cards and their quantities?  How many players are there?  What are the other rules? Since you describe only two options ("lose 3 health" or "pick ... again"), obviously giving each a $1/6$ probability does not fully describe what can happen.

Comment: Hey @whuber is this still on hold given that the question has been clarified to meet your requirements?

Comment: @Kitter I haven't voted to reopen because I still can't figure out what is being asked.  As far as I can tell, one can lose at most 9 points in this situation, so beginning with 20 points--as stated--it's impossible to get below 11 points. Since that's such a trivial calculation I'm confident that's *not* what's being asked--but I can't tell what *is* being asked. There still seems to be a lot of crucial information missing concerning *all* the possible states of the game, their transition probabilities, and the starting state.

Comment: You could lose an arbitrary number of points by hitting the two more followed by lose 3 points followed by two more.

Comment: @KitterCatter Exactly! I honestly don't know what precisely causes the confusion at that point. I'll add a bit more explanation, nonetheless.

Comment: The use of Markov chain might be throwing people off since typically you would encode the entire state information. Anyways there is an analytic answer which could be derived by figuring out the probability of a cycle and run it for the first 18life you would have a split of either losing the last bit due to a 3 with no more spins or a 3 with one more spin. You would then add-in the lose no life terms starting at 0 and going to inf. Not at a computer so I can't give you some latex or an exact answer. Regardless your answer should be on the order 1/36^7 which is why you wouldn't see it.

Comment: Ok got it: You are looking $\left ( (1/36)^7+(1/36^6 1/6) \right  ) (\sum_{i=0} ^\{\infty} (\frac{4}{36})^i \binom{20+i}{i} = 160137547184727/151115727451828646838272~~1.0597×10^-9
$

Comment: @whuber Unless I miss something, this question seems clear enough to me (even edit aside). You start with 20 points. You activate this object, where as a result (randomly, presumably via die roll) either you lose three points (p=1/6), nothing relevant happens (p=4/6), or this activates twice more (p=1/6). Each activation can lead to further activations if that last result comes up, and it can happen that way for any number of times. I believe the question is after the chance that in this single turn you are reduced to 0 health or less (i.e. 7+ health-losses in the entire resulting chain).

Comment: (Though perhaps COOLSerdash should confirm that's the question.) $\:$ I wonder if this could this not be treated as a birth and death process. I guess it would need two kinds of death though (one causing a loss of health and one not), though we could perhaps apply a Bernoulli on the end once we have a distribution of the total number of deaths at extinction and keep it as an ordinary birth-death. Hmm.

Comment: A quick simulation suggests the probability of exceeding 6 lots of damage should probably be somewhere between about 0.0005 and 0.00063  (565 times in a million simulations), assuming my R code is right; the switch command seems a little wonky

Comment: @Glen_b That is exactly the question, thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @Glen_b What I felt needed explaining what the recursive nature of the process as well as its complete isolation from the rest of the game. Thus the question is *not* "What is the probability of losing the game if ... you draw the special card" but rather what is the chance of losing the game *in this immediate sequence of moves, before play ever passes on to someone else.* I still do not understand what it means to "pick two options," because as far as I can tell the play proceeds by selecting *exactly one* option at a time.

Comment: @whuber In this case I believe "pick two options" is simply "generate two new random selections from the given set of options" ... though that could be better put.

Comment: I agree with @Glen_b. I cannot see how this is different from the standard "Drunk staggers off the bridge" problem where negative binomial probabilities are used to model the number of transitions until a random walk exceeds a threshold.